# Gpg signature document

Tags: signature, michigan

The following is a hypothetical question only.

If a hypothetical person (living in Michigan) signs a paper document with both their signature and gpg key stating the key is valid as their signature, unless they sign a second line revoking the signature, and then get the document witnessed and notarized, can their key be considered their legal signature for matters such as wills or other documents?

Comment: In what jurisdiction?

Comment: This would be in Michigan

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

People can be bound by any mark they represent as their signature. People who can not write can be bound with an "X", for example. So there is no need to go through the trouble and formality of getting a notarized document.

*This is not legal advice. And I am not an attorney. If you need legal advice to help you with a particular case, hire a real lawyer. Treat the advice you get here the same way you would as if it came from a group of random strangers at a neighborhood cookout. And never take legal advice from strangers on the internet.*